# Foundation 4 Orbit - Deeplinks sending me to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm trying to implement an Orbit slider into my page. This works fine with just images and regular bullets, but when I add deeplinks to this, the # href of each deeplink is triggered and i'm sent back to the top of the page. I don't even know if the data-orbit-link is working or not.

```
<div class="row">
  <ul id="featuredCom" data-orbit>
    <li data-orbit-slide="image-1">
      <img src="images/featureimages/slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-orbit-slide="image-2">
      <img src="images/featureimages/slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-orbit-slide="image-3">
    <img src="images/featureimages/slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
 <div class="row">
   <ul class="inline-list">
      <li><a href="#" data-orbit-link="image-1">Image One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-orbit-link="image-2">Image Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-orbit-link="image-3">Goto Three 3</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#featuredCom').orbit({

 });
});
</script>
```

I haven't altered anything in the orbit.js file so I can't see what would be causing this. Read the Foundation 4 orbit docs back and forth to see if i'm missing anything, but even when copy their code, the deeplinks behave the same way. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript: void(0);

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" data-orbit-link="image-1">Image One</a>
```

And use

```
$(document).foundation();
```